# Why is BindingListCollectionView sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, icollectionview

I have an extension to the `ICollectionView` interface that allows me to handle multi-selection (`IMultiSelectCollectionView`). I want to provide an implementation that is compatible with `BindingListCollectionView` but that class is sealed. Does anyone know why this design decision was made?

Comment: Sealing is usually done when the someone depends on implementation details of a class that cannot be changed. Best example is the `ImageList` class in .NET, which is a wrapper around the native ImageList control. You cannot give a `ListView` any other kind of ImageList other than the one that wraps the native ImageList, because the ListView **requires** that Imagelist wrap the native control. Even if you wanted to create a descendant ImageList that supports alpha blended PNG images, you can't use it. So BindingListCollectionView is sealed because someone depends violating its encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

Sealing a class usually denotes a safeguard to a derived class that might dramatically change the basic behavior of the original one. Anyway, I don't know what's the real meaning for sealing that class.